# PHP variables resetting after passing javascript variables through AJAX post

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, scope

I'm trying to make some SQL queries using PHP in Wordpress, to auto populate and check values on a gravity form against the existing database.

To do that however, I'm going to need to pass some javascript variables to php, then use that to interact and pull that data back to the form. As someone with minimal web dev background, easier said then done.

My main issue is with an AJAX call that properly carries over a value, but only to the action function. All other calls will show null (I assume due to scoping, but globals don't seem to help).

The main relevant PHP is in a custom plugin as follows:

```
$address = 0;

function my_enqueue() {
    wp_register_script( 'lead-scheduler', null);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'lead-scheduler', plugins_url( '/lead_ajax.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery') );
    wp_localize_script( 'lead-scheduler', 'leadajax', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'lead_ajax', null);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'lead_ajax' );
 }
add_action( 'init', 'my_enqueue' );

function handle_request(){
    //Check post address, then apply to global variable
    echo $_POST['address'] . "\n";
    global $address;
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    echo $address . "\n";
    wp_die("RIP");
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_handle_request', 'handle_request' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_handle_request', 'handle_request' ); 

function functionCaller() {
    if (is_page ('')) { 
        ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
                $(function(){

                    var addressField = document.getElementById('input_22_2');
                    var temp;

                    //Set up event listener
                    addressField.onchange = addressCheck;

                    function addressCheck(){
                        //Get foreign script
                        $.getScript("/wp-content/plugins/lead-scheduler/lead_ajax.js", function(){
                            //Wait until done to execute console.log
                            $.when(adrCheck()).done(function(){
                                console.log("Logging: " + "<?php global $address; echo $address ?>");
                            });
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
            </script>
        <?php
    }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'functionCaller'); ?>
```

The AJAX call comes from a JS file that I call to:

```
//AJAX
function adrCheck(){
    jQuery(document).ready( function() {
        console.log("called")
        var addressField = document.getElementById('input_22_2').value;
      jQuery.ajax({
         type : "post",
         url : leadajax.ajax_url,
         data : {action: "handle_request", address: addressField},
         success: function(response) {
            console.log(response)
         },error: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }
      })   
    })
}
```

The call seems to work, as the echo in `handle_request()` works fine. But calling that variable anywhere else returns null. `$.when.done` doesn't seem to do much, nor does anything synchronous.

I'm sure there's something super elementary that I'm missing, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: It doesn't work like that. Even if the rest of the code is fine, the `console.log` command in your `done()` will show the values of those variables at the time the script is inserted into the `<head>`, not at the time of the ajax call. Unlike JS, PHP isn't a live environment that keeps running; the scripts / functions only run when a request from the browser comes in, and as soon as the script / function has finished and the reply was sent back, all variables are gone.

Comment: Oh okay, that makes sense, thanks! Would there be a method for storing the info for transactions that you could suggest? I suppose I could just add the sql query into the handle_request, and have individual handles for multiple fields. Then I can just check if it's working based on database changes.

Comment: Whichever PHP script/function starts running when you make your AJAX call, it has to do all the work, then send back the reply. The only way to retain data between AJAX calls is to use $_SESSION or write it to the hard disk/database.